# Blockchain API - Returns "Read timed out" when calling my website callback

Tags: blockchain, php

I'm receiving payments using Blockchain API.

The receiving payment part works but after that, when it's supposed to call a link on my website to inform about the payment, it's not working.
I'm using blockchain's callback tester found on their API page at https://blockchain.info/api/api_receive

My website should return `Ignoring test callback` but it returns `Read timed out`. Also it returns the same on every link from my website I put in.

P.S: I'm using an SSL certificate and in my `.htaccess` I'm forcing the website to request to go to `https://` from `http://`.